# How to build different versions of apps with different skins/branding?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating a generic app which will have different builds for different customers. The app is 99.5% identical for each customer, the difference being each is branded with the customer's  own particular images and text and app icon etc.

Obviously this could be done using flags such as:

```
#if defined (CUSTOMER_A)
    NSString* text = @"Text for customer A";
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customerAImage"];
#elseif defined (CUSTOMER_B)
    NSString* text = @"Text for customer B";
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customerBImage"];
```

But obviously I'd like to avoid this and just have:

```
   NSString* text = @"Text";
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
```

(The text would be localizable, so it would be using NSLocalizedString in the final version).

I was wondering if a possible approach would be to place the project into a workspace along with a number of static libraries, each of which contains the specific text and images for each customer and then use different schemes to create different builds. So Scheme A would create a target built with the main project and static library A for example.

I started with a small proof of concept but before going too far with it I'd first like to check this is a feasible and reasonable approach, or if there's a better alternative. If it is feasible then a few questions come to mind:

- how can an image in a static library be accessed from the code in the main project? Does a bundle have to be created to access the contents of the library, how is this done?
- is it possible to change the application desktop and marketplace icons depending upon which scheme is used?
- is it possible to specify a different set of distribution certificates etc. to be used per scheme?
- is it true that static libraries cannot contain localized variants?

This is for iOS so its not possible to use a framework for this.

Thanks for any feedback.

(P.S. the build system will be automated using Jenkins).

Comment: I don't think workspaces or libraries are necessary for distinct assets.  If you have separate folders for each customer but with same-named files, you can create separate targets for each customer and adjust what gets included in the "copy resources" build phase.  (I assume Jenkins will use whatever target/scheme you tell it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to create multiple targets in your project and have 
resource folders for each target (customer/brand).
Here's how to accomplish this:

1. Create two new Resource Folders 
   a. Resources_Customer1
   b. Resource_Customer2
2. Copy the appropriate resources into the respective folders
3. Select Project -> Targets
4. Duplicate the Target
5. Customize the Resources Name in [Copy Build Resources] so that it points to the appropriate
   customer/brand
6. Test and Verify the appropriate Target runs based upon the Target selected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What am i exactly suppose to do in step 5?

Comment: I just want to point out that this is the approach my current employer took and it turned out to be a nightmare to maintain. Targets do *not* lend themselves well to branding. Targets are designed for *different* builds (e.g. targeting different devices, with different feature sets, etc.), not the same build with different resources. After you have more than a few brands you will find targets are just unwieldy. One of the biggest drawbacks is how much work you have to go through just to create a new brand.

Comment: @chaiguy I'm currently dealing with the same scaling problems for managing many brand-based targets. Did you guys land on any kind of better solution? Writing a custom build script looks error prone.

Comment: @Seth We have since moved to a post-build branding shell script and let me tell you it is so much nicer (not to mention loads faster to do the building/branding). The trickiest part was probably figuring out how to re-sign the bundle after modification, but once that was solved things have been going great. Couldn't be happier. Having just a single target to maintain in the project is so much simpler. If you have any questions or run into problems I'd be happy to help! (Also, the brand script only takes effect post-build; there's no custom logic inserted into the normal build process at all).

Comment: @devios How did you manage to do this? Could you say, build your generic app, modify an image in the ipa, resign and deliver?

Comment: Exactly. The app bundle structure is quite simple, and with a little bit of codesign magic (and the right keys and profiles) you can swap out the resources and modify any plists and then just sign it and zip it back up again, good as new.

Comment: @devios after modifying an image and resigning, I'm unable to install the ipa through xcode. I get an error that the bundle has been modified. I must be missing something. Know of an article or blog post on how to do this?

Comment: @AllDayer Make sure you sign both the bundle's executable file as well as the entire .app bundle. Make sure you supply an entitlements file and have the valid profiles and certificates installed on your machine. Take a look [here](http://www.enterpriseios.com/forum/topic/Resigning_3rd_party_apps) and [here](https://sholtz9421.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/digitally-resigning-ipa/) for ideas.

Comment: @AllDayer It definitely takes some trial and error and research. Didn't mean to imply it was a breeze, but it's definitely possible. I'm considering writing an in-depth answer to this question myself.

Comment: @devios - why don't post it as an answer then? I would definitely upvote it

Comment: @Mixaz I posted an answer with the high-level approach. I will elaborate on it as needed.

Answer (score 6):

How many variants do you plan on supporting? Having a target/project/etc becomes unwieldy if you have more than a handful. This is roughly what we do:

- Jenkins monitors the source control and builds any new commits it sees.
- Jenkins archives the output .app along with a collection of "skins"
- A home-brewed website hooks into the Jenkins API and lists all the permutations of (branch, skin).
- The "user" selects a (branch, skin) and the home-brewed site calls a script that "applies" the skin to the .app bundle, signs it and packages it into an .ipa that is then installed to the user's device.

The skin "application" process basically consists of providing a list of "skin" directories, which are files to be copied into the application bundle. Any duplicate files are overwritten by the skin. The application's base `Info.plist` is merged with any changes specified in the skin directory.

Essentially, we try to separate out the skinning as much as possible from the code itself. We have found that any solution involving Xcode itself involves much manual self-removal of hair from developers' scalps.

Comment: +1 for the description of a clever skinning/branding system, and for "manual self-removal of hair from developers' scalps".

Comment: +1 This definitely sounds like the way to go with a large number of skins/brands and I agree Xcode-based solutions are not up to snuff.

Comment: One question: How do you manage code signing? Do you have to re-sign the .app bundle after its plist is modified?

Comment: @chaiguy Yes, we have to resign the app bundle after modifying the plist or any of the contents. It's part of our script.

Comment: Thanks @SedateAlien, I got it working! Already I can tell this is going to make our branding process orders of magnitudes faster and simpler. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

We have been applying a post-build process inspired in part by @SedateAlien's answer for about 3 years now at my current employer and I have to say it is definitely the way to go if you are dealing with more than just a few brands.

It's not exactly a walk in the park, but once you get everything finally working properly it will save you tons of time, as well as keeping your project clean and simple.

Here's the high-level approach we took:

1. Design and build your app project with a single target that will act as your prototype, i.e. just a single brand or "unskinned" variant. You will perform most of your development against this target so make sure it has enough base resources to be fully usable.
2. Set up a "brand resources" repository somewhere to hold the different brand assets. We use a "brand.config" file in each brand's directory that contains various brand-specific info like app name, bundle id, etc, as well as the various well-known resource files that will be swapped into the bundle.
3. Set up a build server (we use Jenkins) or a shell script to perform the branding process based on a built prototype .app. The brand process works like so:
4. Copy the entire prototype .app bundle to a new directory and remove any code signatures.
5. Use Plistbuddy to modify the bundle's plist based on the params in brand.config.
6. Swap-out the well-known resources (images, etc.) in the bundle with the resources from the brand's resource directory.
7. Codesign the app executable and bundle and zip up into an .ipa.

The trickiest part will no doubt be the codesigning. You will probably need to use an entitlements file and will also have to make sure the certificates are properly identified and installed on your build machine.

If you run into issues, don't give up. It *is* possible I promise! I will try to help with any specific issues people have in the comments, but understand it's been a while since I actively developed this so I won't be able to be too detailed.

I should also mention we've never had any issues with App Store submissions concerning this process, and we submit a *lot* of apps (100+ for each update).

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly this same thing for a company so I can share with you how I did it. I was with you until you said Jenkins, since I used Xcode, but maybe you can make it work.

Essentially you create one library project that is included in your "skin" application projects. The skins include any app-specific image, the plist, and possibly even a few methods. You create a .h file that is used by the framework with one class that vends objects, or functions, or globals - you decide. The header for this file is included in the library to allow the library to build.

For instance, suppose it has "extern UIImage *mainBackgroundImage;", and you reference that in the library (ie you retrieve it for display).

The "skin" application of course has the .m (or .c) file to resolve all the public items you promised in your .h file.

In Xcode, you would create a library project. You would include that in every "skin" project (keeping in mind you need to get a dependency on the library in the Build Phase pane, and make sure the library is included in the Link phase. If you use categories in your library you need to force_load the library by adding a special line to Link Flags in each target's project.

You can in a half hour build a little test harness with two projects to convince yourself that this works just fine.

Comment: So you are essentially reversing what I posted - the 99.5 of generic code goes into the library and then create separate projects for each app. That seems more sensible. But the generic code contains a lot of strings that is common for each build, but I read a posting on here that libraries cannot contain localizable strings. Did you encounter such an issue?

Comment: I didn't have to deal with localization so I cannot say yes or no. BTW, the difficulty with one huge project is that everytime you add anything you need to deal with a huge list of projects. Anyway, there are many ways to solve this YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting for anyone who stumbles across this dilemma that the introduction of asset catalogs in iOS7 make this problem very easy to solve in XCode. I have projects with multiple targets and asset catalogs makes it easy to handle resources, custom build settings and code signing issues all in one place. Not only that, when Apple introduces a new form factor (eg. iPhone 6+) it is easy to see which of asset catalogs are not up to date (eg. missing the iPhone 6+ launch screen). Very flexible too. Let's say you have 12 targets needing skinning, 7 are schools, 5 are workplaces. Create a new asset catalog called `SchoolMedia` and another called `WorkMedia`. Into each catalog add an image set called `main_symbol`. In your XIB, use `main_symbol`. Make `SchoolMedia` a member of the school targets and `WorkMedia` a member of the work targets. The right `main_symbol` will be displayed depending on the target. The permutations are endless and XCode's visual interface makes it easy to understand what is going on (even if it was a bit unmanageable in the past)